# Mount NFS on Windows XP

Tags: nfs, windows-xp

I want to know if anybody has done any hands on test mounting NFS on Windows XP using "Windows services for Unix" http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=274

I know that it should work but I want to know if people have had any problem with it or can it reliably replace Samba sharing?

Comment: above link is 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in the most technical of senses. Reliability is heavily dependent on consistent and simplistic use. If you just need a few XP clients to connect it will work. If you need to do anything complicated, especially involving user mapping or complicated access controls, it'll probably fail spectacularly.

Comment: I have rather high bursts of IO, with tens of users each having their own set of permissions. What about the Win 7 support, is it the same?

Comment: Win7 support is miles better in terms of reliability, but user mapping and perms are generally similar. The perms problems come from Unix/NFS using much simpler ACEs than Windows. If you can live within the standard UGO/RWX, then you shouldn't have any problems. Side note: Win7 has NFS built in, but only in Enterprise and Ultimate versions; you can't add it on like XP.